# Запятая в союзах по типу «после того как»

Tags: запятые, союзы

Насколько мне известно, часто (я понимаю, что не всегда, потому что это всё-таки определяется желанием автора, но часто) такие обороты не разделяются запятой, когда стоят в начале предложения.

Возник следующий вопрос: стоит ли ставить запятую, если оборот стоит не в абсолютном начале предложения, а после, например, слова «но» или «даже»? Просто в речи такие вещи, как по мне, произносятся быстро, и поэтому мне кажется, что из-за этого запятую лучше не ставить, то есть, допустим, начать предложение с «но после того как...», «даже после того как...» или «а после того как...».

*Не спорю, всё это очень субъективно, но хочется узнать хотя бы некую тенденцию в этом вопросе, если она есть.*

Comment: См Розенталь  5. Постановка запятой между присоединительным союзом (в начале предложения, после точки) и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом зависит от значения союза..  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140

Comment: Еще вариант с примерами  – это Нацкорпус  https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Ck8qGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCLAoqCigKA3JlcRIhCh/QvdC%2BINC/0L7RgdC70LUg0YLQvtCz0L4g0LrQsNC6MAE=  Здесь лучше задавать вопросы по конкретным предложениям. Поищите непонятный пример и задайте по нему вопрос.

Comment: Большое спасибо!